# Missing template error after using javascript / jquery sorting

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 2.3.18 app that allows users to drag and drop items in a list. I am receiving the following error when users drag and drop:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template lists/sorting.erb in view path app/views)

Below is the related javascript. I know that Rails is looking for a template, but I'm not sure what I should point users to because I'd like for them to just stay on the page but be able to work on their list. Sorry, I'm pretty inexperienced!

```
//  Lists Sorting
    $('#items').sortable({
        stop: function() { 
                $.post('/lists/sorting', { item_sort: $('#items').sortable('serialize') });
            }
    });
```

Comment: you need to add `redirect_to request.referrer` to your sorting action on your controller if you want the same page as the response of your post request

Answer (score 1):

I can assume you have lists_controller with sorting method. In your case the view file is missing for your request. It actually a Ajax request so it will be resolved once you add sorting.js.erb file in views/lists path.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used, `$.post('/lists/sorting')`, I assume that you have `listing controller` and `sorting` method in that controller.

If you want to use ajax requests and dont want the `erb` files, just use `json` response. If you use json response, the rails will not search for an `erb` file,

Try this in your controller.

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
    def sorting
        @lists = List.find(params[:id]) // Your line here
        render json: @lists
    end
end
```

Now this `json` response will be returned to your ajax call.